# How to start an activity only once per session?

Tags: android

I have ActivityB that I want to start from ActivityA after the user clicks on a button on ActivityA. However, I *only* want to start ActivityB from ActivityA one time-- if the user goes back to ActivityA and clicks on the button a second time, I do not want ActivityB to start.

However, I would like for this to *restart* if the application is simply closed and reopened. *(Meaning, this is unlike an isFirstRun for SharedPreferences solution, which, in my understanding, stays set until app reinstallation.)*

What is the best way to do this?

**My current approach:** I already have an Intent that I pass around to start ActivityB from ActivityA. This intent gets created every time the app opens. I store a boolean called FirstTimeLaunch and set it to true. I launch ActivityB from ActivityA if FirstTimeLaunch is true, and after I start it I set FirstTimeLaunch to false.

I'd like to know what are other ways I can accomplish this behavior.
Are there ways that I can use either:

- Shared Preferences?
- Session Management?
- Something else ?!?!

Thanks for any clues or directions I can investigate. :)

Comment: I think that is a good solution, using a boolean in Application class, setting it to true on creation, setting it to false after the activity B is shown. I think that's the easiest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for how tasks are managed in an application. You can find more details here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks

I think what would work for your requirement is using the 'singleTask' as the launchMode attribute for Activity's B manifest entry.

Answer (score 0):

Set a field in activity A indicating that activity B has been started.  Save this value in activity A's `onSaveInstanceState(...)`, and restore it in `onCreate(...)` or `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`.

Setting a value in the `Application` will not work reliably.  When activity A is finished and restarted, the same `Application` instance *may* be reused without another call to `onCreate()`.  Setting a static value anywhere will also be unreliable.  The activities and application *may* be destroyed any time the app is in the background, and when they are recreated, the static value will not be automatically restored.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a static boolean activityOpened variable which is false by default and in void onCreate method it will be true and in onDesrtroy method it will be false again.
Now onClickListner on button of class ActivityA will be like below...

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
    if(ActivityB.activityOpened)
    {Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);}
    else
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    }});
```

by this code button will create activity if not created else restart or resume to by putting it into foreground.